# What makes a symbol in an ELF library an object or normal one?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, elf

I have an application that is loading some plugins via `dlopen`, specifically  `dlopen(name, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_DEEPBIND)`. There are some plugins (provided in binary form) that load fine, but the plugin I am trying to build fails to load with an error:

```
/opt/app/plugins/plugin.so: undefined symbol: Log_Modules
```

All the plugins refer to that symbol, and the library that provides it is loaded in the process. However the entry printed by `objdump -D` differs. In the plugins that load it says

```
00000000      DO *UND*       00000000              Log_Modules
```

and in the library defining it it says

```
000130dc g    DO .data       00000004  Base        Log_Modules
```

while in the module I built it says

```
00000000      D  *UND*       00000000              Log_Modules
```

The manual page of [`objdump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) just says that the flag means

> The symbol is the name of a function (F) or a file (f) or an object (O) or just a normal symbol (a space).

but I don't see any hint for what the difference between an object and normal symbol is. So

- what is the difference,
- what makes the symbol one or the other at the C or C++ language or linker level and
- is it indeed supposed to make the symbol not resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the difference

The `O` flag corresponds to the `STT_OBJECT` flag, signifying an object, that is a variable.

> what makes the symbol one or the other at the C or C++ language or linker level

Apparently, the linker marks symbols with the `STT_OBJECT` flag only if it actually sees the definition, i.e. when the library that defines it is provided as a dependency. Extern declarations alone are not marked.

> is it indeed supposed to make the symbol not resolve?

When resolving symbols, the linker looks in explicitly listed dependencies, and libraries loaded with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, which includes the dependencies of the main executable. So when the main executable already happens to link the defining library, the plugin will get away with not linking it explicitly, but if it is itself loaded with `dlopen` (without `RTLD_GLOBAL`), it won't.

The absence of the flag itself isn't the problem, but it hints at the actual problem of missing library reference.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but whatever.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, well, yes, it is. I've missed out to point out why the last paragraph was actually the answer though, so I've added it.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference

The symbol table `.st_info` contains `STT_OBJECT` instead of `STT_FUNC`.

> what makes the symbol one or the other at the C or C++ language or linker level

At `C` level, compiler will mark function labels with `@function` when emitting assembly code, and assembler will add `STT_FUNC` flag when emitting symbol table.

> is it indeed supposed to make the symbol not resolve?

No. Your problem most likely is unrelated to that.

In general, `objdump` is the *wrong* tool to look at ELF files (it maps to BFD data model, which has been obsolete for the last 20+ years). Use `readelf` instead.

Wild guess: your `plugin.so` defines, but does *not* export the symbol. Use

```
nm -D plugin.so | grep ' Log_Modules$'
nm    plugin.so | grep ' Log_Modules$'
```

If `Log_Modules` shows up in the second command output, but not the first, then my guess is correct.

Comment: Note that all the three lines in my question have the `D` flag, which means that they are in the output of the first command. The output of the second command is empty for the library defining the symbol, because it has been provided stripped.

Comment: … functions work fine. But what I need to know here is when the STT_OBJECT flag is set or not.