# How linker allow multiple definitions of a function template in different object files but only allow one-definition of ordinary functions

Tags: c++, templates, linker, specialization

I know how to use inline keyword to avoid 'multiple definition' while using C++ template. However, what I am curious is that how linker is distinguishing which specialization is full specialization and violating ODR and reporting error, while another specialization is implicit and correctly handle it?

From the `nm` output, we can see duplicated definitions in main.o and other.o for both int-version max() and char-version max(), but C++ linker only reports 'multiple definition error for char-version max()' but let 'char-version max() go a successful link? How linker differentiate them and does this?

```
// tmplhdr.hpp
#include <iostream>

// this function is instantiated in main.o and other.o
// but leads no 'multiple definition' error by linker
template<typename T>
T max(T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << "match generic\n";
    return (b<a)?a:b;
}

// 'multiple definition' link error if without inline
template<>
inline char max(char a, char b)
{
    std::cout << "match full specialization\n";
    return (b<a)?a:b;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "tmplhdr.hpp"

extern int mymax(int, int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << max(1,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mymax(10,20) << std::endl;
    std::cout << max('a','b') << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
// other.cpp
#include "tmplhdr.hpp"

int mymax(int a, int b)
{
    return max(a, b);
}
```

Test output on Ubuntu is reasonable; but output on Cygwin is rather strange and confusing...

==== Test on Cygwin ====

g++ linker only reported 'char max(char, char)' is duplicated.

```
$ g++ -o main.exe main.cpp other.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: 
/tmp/ccYivs3O.o:other.cpp:(.text$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_[_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_]+0x0): 
multiple definition of `char max<char>(char, char)'; 
/tmp/cc7HJqbS.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dumped my .o object file and found no many clues (maybe I am not quite familiar with object format spec.).

```
$ nm main.o | grep max | c++filt.exe
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_Z3maxIiET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 t .text$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 t .text$_Z3maxIiET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_Z3maxIiET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 T char max<char>(char, char) <-- full specialization
0000000000000000 T int max<int>(int, int) <<-- implicit specialization
                 U mymax(int, int)
```

```
$ nm other.o | grep max | c++filt.exe
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 p .pdata$_Z3maxIiET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 t .text$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 t .text$_Z3maxIiET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 r .xdata$_Z3maxIiET_S0_S0_
000000000000009b t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z5mymaxii
0000000000000000 T char max<char>(char, char) <-- full specialization
0000000000000000 T int max<int>(int, int) <-- implicit specialization
0000000000000000 T mymax(int, int)
```

==== Test on Ubuntu ====

This is what I have got on my Ubuntu with g++-9 after having remove `inline` from `tmplhdr.hpp`

```
tony@Win10Bedroom:/mnt/c/Users/Tony Su/My Documents/cpphome$ g++ -o main main.o other.o
/usr/bin/ld: other.o: in function `char max<char>(char, char)':
other.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `char max<char>(char, char)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

'char-version max()' is marked with `T` which is not allowed to have multiple definitions; but 'in-version max()' is marked as `W` which allows multiple definitions. However, I start to be curious why `nm` gives different marks on Cygwin than on Ubuntu?? and Why linker on Cgywin can handle two `T` definitions correctly?

```
tony@Win10Bedroom:/mnt/c/Users/Tony Su/My Documents/cpphome$ nm main.o | grep max | c++filt
0000000000000133 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 T char max<char>(char, char)
0000000000000000 W int max<int>(int, int)
                 U mymax(int, int)
```

```
tony@Win10Bedroom:/mnt/c/Users/Tony Su/My Documents/cpphome$ nm other.o | grep max | c++filt
00000000000000d7 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z3maxIcET_S0_S0_
0000000000000000 T char max<char>(char, char)
0000000000000000 W int max<int>(int, int)
000000000000003e T mymax(int, int)
```

Comment: A full specialization is no longer a template (nothing to deduce) and behaves like a "normal" function (which also requires `inline` in a header).

Comment: Does your `c++filt` change the output? On linux, `nm` shows a `W` (for *weak* symbols) instead of a `T` (for *text* symbols) for these instantiations. Also, Your code compiles in linux with GCC 7.5. So, maybe providing your compiler version might also help (and be important) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @J.P.S. my g++ is 11.2 and c++filt does not change the the 2nd column, but I am on Cygwin environment. If on linux, there is a ```W```, then I can understand why there is no ODR violation during linking phase. My code I presented can compile, but if I remove 'inline' keyword from tmplhdr.hpp, compilation will fail. sorry for the inconsistence in my question.

Comment: Ah, I think, I see the problem. Try to first compile both files individually by `g++ -c main.cpp` and `g++ -c other.cpp`. Then check the symbols with `nm` on both object files (`main.o` and `other.o`). You might notice a difference with and without the keyword `inline`. In my case, both `max` symbols were weak in both object files unless I removed the `inline` keyword, in which case one of the four symbols was `T` which might cause the conflict at linking time (between the `T` and the `W` symbol of `max(char,char)` of both object files).

Comment: @J.P.S. Yes, that's the answer I am looking for. We finally got it. Thanks.

Comment: @TonySu In case you're wondering where my comments went: It looks like my comments no longer served a purpose (the question has been improved), so I deleted them. Feel free to delete your own comments (particularly the replies to me) if you believe they have outlived their usefulness and you want to keep this comment section tidy. ;) (Don't delete them if you see value in keeping them around.)

Comment: @JaMiT I still truly appreciated your hints which finally helped me clarify my questions and provide the minimal experimental example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I start to be curious why nm gives different marks on Cygwin than on Ubuntu?? and Why linker on Cgywin can handle two T definitions correctly?

You need to understand that the `nm` output does *not* give you the full picture.

`nm` is part of binutils, and uses `libbfd`. The way this works is that various object file formats are parsed into `libbfd`-internal representation, and then tools like `nm` print that internal representation in human-readable format.

Some things get "lost in translation". This is the reason you should [~never use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527463/50617) e.g. `objdump` to look at `ELF` files (at least not at the symbol table of the `ELF` files).

As you correctly deduced, the reason multiple `max<int>()` symbols are allowed on Linux is that the compiler emits them as a `W` (weakly defined) symbol.

The same is true for Windows, *except* Windows uses older `COFF` format, which doesn't have weak symbols. Instead, the symbol is emitted into a special `.linkonce.$name` section, and the linker knows that it can select any such section into the link, but should only do that *once* (i.e. it knows to discard all other duplicates of that section in any other object file).

Comment: Aha. you solved the mystery on Cygwin environment. Now I think the mystery has been solved on both Linux and Cygwin environment. Really appreciated your answer!!!